# How do i get the true path to a reg key?

Tags: .net, windows, registry, 32bit-64bit

If you are running a 32 bit app on a 64 bit machine (I am using windows 7) and you write this code

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\XXX")
```

it will actually get the key from

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XXX
```

and not

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\XXX
```

Progromatically given a RegistryKey how do i work out the true path in the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much the True Path, a 32-bit app will always access the registry key in that subkey.  Getting the value that a 64-bit app would see is technically possible, just not with .NET.  You'll have to P/Invoke RegOpenKeyEx() et al so you can specify the [KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28VS.85%29.aspx)

---

UPDATE: addressed in .NET 4.0 with RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey().  The RegistryView argument lets you specify the view you want.  You'd use RegistryView.Registry64 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is a function of whether or not the program was compiled for 32 or 64 bit Windows and whether it's running on 32 or 64 bit Windows. See if below helps:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/92f962d6-7f5e-4e62-ac0a-b8b0c9f552a3